# Characterisation of operator norm on $l^2$

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $A$ be a bounded operator on $l^2(\mathbb C)$ and let $\{e_i\}$ be some orthonormal basis. Is there a sharp characterisation of the operator norm $\|A\|_{\mathcal L(l^2(\mathbb C))}$ in terms of the matrix elements $A_{ij}:=\langle e_i,A e_j\rangle$?

It is straightforward to show that 
$$\sup_k\sum_i|A_{ik}|^2\leq \|A\|_{\mathcal L(l^2(\mathbb C))}^2 \leq \sum_{i,k}|A_{ik}|^2, $$

but simple counterexamples show that neither of the two inequalities can be sharp.

Comment: What would you consider a satisfactory answer to this question in the case of finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces? (That's the special case of this question where $A$ has finite rank.)

Comment: Well, ideally I would like an "equivalence of norms" - type of inequality; something like $c\|A\|\leq |A|\leq C\|A\|$, where |A| can be computed from the matrix elements of A. Note that in a finite-dimensional space, this is provided by the right-hand side of the above inequality. But in infinite dimensions, $\left(\sum_{i,j}|A_{ij}|^2\right)^{\frac 12}$ is the Hilbert-Schmidt-norm which is only finite for a special class of compact operators.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't, even in finite dimension. For instance, let us consider $4\times 4$ matrices where four entries are $1$ and the rest are zero. Let
$$
A_1=\begin{bmatrix} 
1&0&0&0\\ 
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix},
\ \ 
A_2=\begin{bmatrix} 
1&1&0&0\\ 
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
A_3=\begin{bmatrix} 
1&1&0&0\\ 
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix},
\ \  
A_4=\begin{bmatrix} 
1&1&0&0\\ 
1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then, though the sets of entries of the four matrices is the same, we have the four operator norms
$$
\|A_1\|=1,\ \ \ \|A_2\|=\sqrt2,\ \ \ \|A_3\|=\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}},\ \ \|A_4\|=2.
$$